# libUSB, C++, OSX, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, libusb

I need some help with setting up my libusb library. I know that to use a library in c++ (without an IDE) I have to include the header **and** link the library. I do not know if the issue is that the libusb version is 32bit and not 64, or if I have an issue linking the library. I'm new to this so roast me if I'm barking up the wrong tree. **I just want USB serial access for a c++ program.** I've also read that the 32 vs 64 bit thing is about matching your application, not your OS. That makes me more confused because I do not have an application, I have a single source file in a single folder. I would love to continue this project but I cannot seem to get past this.

I cannot use visual studio for the project. (any good free c++ IDEs for enterprise use?)

**Context:**

- Mac OSX Catalina 10.15.4
- I'm trying to link the library [libusb](https://libusb.info/)
- Main working folder: Robot
- Path to lib: Robot/Dependencies/libusb/lib/
- Path to include: Robot/Dependencies/libusb/include/
- inside the
  folder there are these files:

  libusb-1.0.0.dylib,
  libusb-1.0.dylib,
  libusb-1.0.a,
  pckgconfig

**Please help me:**

- statically link this library
- dynaimcally link this library
- **OR** find a workaround

here is the thing I'm trying to run. There is nothing wrong with it (it was copied and pasted, only the #include is modified), the problem is library linking (I think):

```
#include "Dependencies/libusb/include/libusb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)
{
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    uint8_t path[8];
    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)",
            desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
            libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));

        r = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, sizeof(path));
        if (r > 0) {
            printf(" path: %d", path[0]);
            for (j = 1; j < r; j++)
                printf(".%d", path[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0){
        libusb_exit(NULL);
        return (int) cnt;
    }

    print_devs(devs);
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some of my faliures:

- naive try to build:

```
$ g++ run.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libusb_exit", referenced from:
      _main in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_free_device_list", referenced from:
      _main in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_get_bus_number", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_get_device_address", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_get_device_descriptor", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_get_device_list", referenced from:
      _main in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_get_port_numbers", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-6f49db.o
  "_libusb_init", referenced from:
      _main in run-6f49db.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

- try to link:

```
$ g++ run.cpp -I/blah/ROBOT/Dependencies/libusb/include -L /blarg/ROBOT/Dependencies/libusb/lib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libusb_exit", referenced from:
      _main in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_free_device_list", referenced from:
      _main in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_get_bus_number", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_get_device_address", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_get_device_descriptor", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_get_device_list", referenced from:
      _main in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_get_port_numbers", referenced from:
      print_devs(libusb_device**) in run-655ac8.o
  "_libusb_init", referenced from:
      _main in run-655ac8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

- sorta build and then link:

```
$ g++ -c run.cpp
$ g++ -o run run.o /bagh/ROBOT/Dependencies/libusb/lib/libusb-1.0.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_CFDataGetBytes", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFDataGetLength", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFDataGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFNumberGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFNumberGetValue", referenced from:
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      _darwin_close in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_release_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRetain", referenced from:
      _darwin_open in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopAddSource", referenced from:
      _darwin_open in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopGetCurrent", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopRemoveSource", referenced from:
      _darwin_close in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_release_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopRun", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopSourceCreate", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopSourceSignal", referenced from:
      _darwin_exit in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopStop", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFRunLoopWakeUp", referenced from:
      _darwin_exit in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFUUIDGetConstantUUIDWithBytes", referenced from:
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes", referenced from:
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService", referenced from:
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _process_new_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_detached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_attached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_clear_iterator in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOKitWaitQuiet", referenced from:
      _darwin_hotplug_poll in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
  "_IONotificationPortCreate", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IONotificationPortDestroy", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOObjectRelease", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _process_new_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_detached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      ...
    "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", referenced from:
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceAddMatchingNotification", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      CFString in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kCFAllocatorSystemDefault", referenced from:
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kCFRunLoopCommonModes", referenced from:
      _darwin_open in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kCFRunLoopDefaultMode", referenced from:
      _darwin_close in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_release_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kIOMasterPortDefault", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_hotplug_poll in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

with -framework foundation:

```
$ g++ -o run run.o /Users/xxandervargad/Desktop/ROBOT/Dependencies/libusb/lib/libusb-1.0.a -framework Foundation
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService", referenced from:
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _process_new_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_detached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_attached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_clear_iterator in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOKitWaitQuiet", referenced from:
      _darwin_hotplug_poll in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IONotificationPortCreate", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IONotificationPortDestroy", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOObjectRelease", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_claim_interface in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _process_new_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_devices_detached in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      ...
    "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", referenced from:
      _darwin_kernel_driver_active in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _get_ioregistry_value_number in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry", referenced from:
      _darwin_get_cached_device in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceAddMatchingNotification", referenced from:
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
    "_kIOMasterPortDefault", referenced from:
      _darwin_init in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_hotplug_poll in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
      _darwin_event_thread_main in libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any help would be immensly appreciated. The commands that I tried are from stack overflow already.

Comment: Can you add "-framework Foundation" to your last example?  It would work with clang but I'm not sure about g++...it's been too many years.

Comment: you need to link to the IOKit framework too